# Entity Framework Core 1.1.0 Data type conversion

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a legacy database that stores user comments (and quite a few other text fields) as `blob` datatype, which I cannot change.

I am writing a data access layer that will need to always convert the data to a `string` when it is retrieved from the database, and convert it back to `blob` when saving.

The EF scaffolding tool generated properties as `byte[]` datatype for these entities.

```
public byte[] Comment { get; set; }
```

I noticed that if I simply change the entity property type to `string` it actually does save the data correctly, but loading the data results in a casting error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Byte[]' to type 'System.String'.

*(Interestingly, version 1.0.0 did not throw this error, loading and saving worked ok.)*

**My question is...** Is there a way of configuring EF core to automatically convert this data to string when I retrieve it from the database and back to `blob` when it gets saved back? Or will I need to write a whole bunch of private getters and setters to do this manipulation?

Comment: `byte[]` is a completely different datatype than `string`. Converting a `byte[]` to `string` is dependend on encoding,... EF can't do it for you. Best practice is to leave it as `byte[]` and write a getter that returns you the string-representation like `public string MyString { get { return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(MyBytes); } }`

Comment: I think your best bet is buddy properties until https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/242 comes to fruition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition for my comment on your answere, if you don't want to add getters and setters and want to have clean code, you could also work with extension-methods:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static byte[] GetBytes(this string @this, System.Text.Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        return (encoding??Encoding.UTF8).GetBytes(@this);
    }

    public static string GetString(this byte[] @this, System.Text.Encoding encoding = null)
    {
        return (encoding??Encoding.UTF8).GetString(@this);
    }
}
```

you can work with them both this way:

```
myentity.Comment = "my comment".GetBytes();
string comment = myentity.Comment.GetString();
```

take care of the default-value in the code, that is UTF8, you can change it to the encoding you want to use, or enter another encoding like

```
byte[] myBytes = "my comment".GetBytes(Encoding.ASCII);
```

your win: you don't have to specify a getter/setter to each property using `byte[]`

Comment: Thanks for this solution. Whilst both the current answers will effectively help solve this issue I have chosen this as the accepted answer purely because it works best for my particular requirement. Hopefully the EF Core team will implement this http://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/242 soon.

Answer (score 2):

Converting the `byte[]` into a `string` *always* requires an `Encoding`. Since EF does not know which encoding to use, such an automatic conversion is not possible.

What you *can* do though is to mark your Comment property as private and to create a wrapper property that converts the value to a string with an `Encoding` of your choice:

```
partial class MyEntity
{
    private string m_commentText = null;
    public string CommentText
    {
        get {
            if ((m_commentText == null) && (Comment != null)) {
                m_commentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Comment);      
            }
            return m_commentText;
        }
        set {
            m_commentText = value;
            if (value != null) {
                Comment = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
            }
            else {
                Comment = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This solution stores the text in a backer field to avoid multiple conversions from `byte[]` to `string`. If you need the `Comment` property to stay public, you need to remove the backer field to avoid data inconsistency:

```
partial class MyEntity
{
    public string CommentText
    {
        get {
            if (Comment != null) {
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Comment);      
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }
        }
        set {
            if (value != null) {
                Comment = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value);
            }
            else {
                Comment = null;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe specify `byte[] Comment`-property in the entity to make it a bit clearer

Comment: Yeah, I would, but that part is auto-generated. There is not much point in specifying the auto-generated property. That's why included `partial`.

Comment: Ah I see, so maybe add to your answere, that the generated class also has to be `partial`. Or is the generated always a partial class? I don't know what EF scaffolding tool generates ;)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger: EF always generates entites as partial classes to allow your custom extensions.

Comment: @Sefe: Thanks for the very useful comments & answer. This solution creates an issue with EF expecting `CommentText` as a database field. Even if this is fixable, the extra getters and setters would be a lot of work to implement for my particular scenario.

Comment: @Bandito: You can use `CommentText` for data display, but you can not use it in a LINQ query. EF can not map this property to a DB field. This is also logical. You can't make a query to a blob field with a text. In queries you will have to convert the text you compare against to a byte array first.

Comment: @Sefe: The issue was that because `CommentText` was added to the model, EF would error when any data was retrieved because it was adding that to the queries. I eventually resolved this by adding the `ignore` attribute. Thanks again.

Comment: @Bandido: Did you add the property in the model designer? The way to add custom properties is to create another code file with the partial class definition and to leave the model unchanged.